# how to check JDBC connection is live or closed Using try-with-resources?

Tags: java, jdbc

Once try-with-resources statement execution completion after how to check JDBC connection is live or closed ?

Code :

```
try (Connection conn = ConnectionString.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement psmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_Queries.GET_PUBLISHER_ID_QUERY);
     ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery();)
{
   psmt.setString(1, appId);
   while (rs.next()) {
     publisherId = rs.getString(Schema.PUBLISHER_PUBLISHID);
   }

   //System.out.println(conn != null ? "live" : "close");
}
```

Comment: your print statement is inside the try-with-resource block, so it won't be closed yet. Even more, the scope of the Connection object is inside the block. It wouldn't be visible outside of it. Can you add more details to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Using java 1.7 feature try-with-resources statement after completion of try-with-resources statement i want to know the status of existing connection is still live or closed ?. As per AutoCloseable interface the connections are closed automatically when try-with-resources statement is completed.

Comment: It is required to be closed at the end; if it isn't it is a bug in the driver. Why do you want to know this? Are you testing a JDBC driver, or are you just curious. Otherwise just transform the try-with-resources to an equivalent try-finally and check the connection after calling `close()` yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that using the try-with-resource block, you are creating an inner scope for your connection. The try-with-resource closes the connection and the conn object scope ends, thus is ready for garbage collection. [Read more about scope here.](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

To check this, run this code

```
String url, username, pass;
url = "your-connection-url";
username = "db-username";
pass = "db-password";
Connection outerConnection = null;

try (Connection innerConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, pass);
     PreparedStatement psmt = innerConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT 1");
     ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery();)
{
   while (rs.next()) {
       System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
   }

   outerConnection = innerConnection;

   // after the try catch, innerConnection won't exist anymore
   // (the scope ends, the compiler compains if you access it outside the block!)
} catch (SQLException e) 
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}

if (outerConnection != null) {
    try {
       System.out.println("Is closed? " + outerConnection.isClosed());
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("Is null");
}
```

In the console you'll get

```
1
Is closed? true
```

Comment: Nice explanation @ outerConnection.isClosed(); Thank you aepure.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Connection object scope is limited to the try block, it's not visible outside of it.

Secondly, you said it yourself, all resources in a try-with-resources statement, which must all implement AutoCloseable, are closed at the end of the statement. So even if your Connection was visible, it would be closed.